# How many rows does SEMANTICSIMILARITYTABLE produce

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have the following table in SQL Server 2014 with Full Text Index and semantic search enabled on 'Content' column.

`FullTextTable(Id INT PRIMARY KEY,Content NVARCHAR(MAX))`

I am trying to use SEMANTICSIMILARITYTABLE from Sql Server to find the rows that have similar contents to row 25. It so happens that I have the exact same content for rows 15-49. I get the score column as 1 for rows with same content.

Case 1 :

```
SELECT * FROM SEMANTICSIMILARITYTABLE(FullTextTable,Content,25) AS KEY_TBL  
ORDER BY KEY_TBL.score DESC;
GO
```

Result:

```
source_column_id | matched_column_id | matched_document_key | score
2                  2                   15                     1
2                  2                   16                     1
2                  2                   17                     1
2                  2                   18                     1
2                  2                   19                     1
2                  2                   20                     1
2                  2                   21                     1
2                  2                   22                     1
2                  2                   23                     1
2                  2                   24                     1
```

Question : Why does the above query produce only 10 results? The rows 26-49 also have the exact same content. The official documentation by Microsoft(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492218.aspx) contains an example that restricts the result to 10 rows by using `Top 10`. However I could not find any documentation that this is an internal limit.

Case 2 : I tried limiting the result set to avoid rows with ID 15 and 16.

```
SELECT *
FROM SEMANTICSIMILARITYTABLE(FullTextTable,Content,25) AS KEY_TBL
where matched_document_Key not in (15,16)   
ORDER BY KEY_TBL.score DESC;
GO
```

Result:

```
source_column_id | matched_column_id | matched_document_key | score
2                  2                   17                     1
2                  2                   18                     1
2                  2                   19                     1
2                  2                   20                     1
2                  2                   21                     1
2                  2                   22                     1
2                  2                   23                     1
2                  2                   24                     1
```

Question : While the rows 15 and 16 are now removed from the result set, why isn't 2 more added to make the number 10? Hence this number 10 cannot be an internal limitation of the function for maximum rows. Can someone explain?

Note: I have attempted to re-build the index (complete and incremental) between case 1 and case 2. Still got the same result.

Appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an internal limit to the rows returned. This link is from 2012 but it still seems to be true!

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d9bdd8d5-dec4-4076-bcb8-692f1d509c74/semanticsimilaritytable-sql2012-1102100-why-pull-max-of-only-10-results?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Comment: A link might go stale in the future - better summarize the answer here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).